# Connect MBP 2015 to external monitor 2560 x 1080 resolution?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, resolution, hdmi, displayport

I need to connect a MBP 15" to an external monitor with 2560 x 1080 resolution (this http://www.trustedreviews.com/lg-29ea93-review ).

I already tried **HDMI** to **HDMI** but the text looks very bad (sharp).

I guess I need to use **Thunderbolt** to **Display Port** but I don't know which cable adapter is the correct one.

Then my question is which is correct connection and what cable do I need to buy?

**The MBP has:**

- Thunderbolt
- USB 3
- HDMI

**The monitor has:**

- DisplayPort
- DVI-D Dual Link
- HDMI
- USB 3.0

Comment: HDMI to HDMI should work (it works between my MBP and 1080p Asus monitor). Try playing with the Display settings in System prefs.

Comment: @JohnRamos The 'Display' tab only allows me to change from 'Default for display' to 'Scaled'. Refresh only allows 60 Hertz (NTSC). Can you tell me what more can I do here?

Comment: @JohnRamos Do you use the standar 'HDMI' or the 'HDMI HIGH SPEED'?

Comment: Isn't there an `Underscan` slider? And I just use the standard HDMI cable that came with the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect your monitor to a Thunderbolt port using a DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort cable like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C7RIL3C); other lengths are available if 3 Feet is not long enough for your purposes.

I connected my LG 25UM65 (2560x1080 native resolution) to my MacBookPro11,3 (mid 2014 15" Retina) three different ways, HDMI to HDMI, Thunderbolt to DisplayPort, and Thunderbolt to HDMI. The Thunderbolt to HDMI connection is not useful (the maximum resolution it offers is 1920x1080), but the other two connections both work at 2560x1080@60Hz, and the visual quality is comparable across the two connections (but both look blotchy compared to the Retina display). A UHD display (3840x2160) is a better choice than 2560x1080 to maximize the display quality of Thunderbolt 2 (DisplayPort 1.2).

It's possible that a better HDMI cable will improve the display quality (the one I'm using is labeled HDMI HIGH SPEED). You can determine (and change) the resolution and refresh rate from System Preferences (Display) by choosing `Scaled` rather than `Default for display` (using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while choosing `Scaled` can provide more choices on some displays). A 2015 Mac's HDMI port is capable of driving 2560x1080@60 Hz, provided the display has a suitable HDMI input (HDMI 1.3 is sufficient, but HDMI 1.2 probably isn't). If your display has multiple HDMI inputs, you might try all of them to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tried both cables: 1- https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B00J3KFAV2/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 and 2- https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B00C7RJQPY/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: But is not working. Visual quality is very bad. My MBP has these Video Cards: 1- Intel Iris Pro and 2- NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M. And is the monitor: http://www.trustedreviews.com/lg-29ea93-review

Comment: Maybe the monitor is no compatible at all with my MBP ?¿

Comment: Have you determined what resolution is being reported for each connection? Have you tried the same display on a different computer? If the display is being driven at its native resolution, perhaps you're just unaccustomed to such large pixels (at its best this display cannot compare favorably to any Retina display).

Comment: Not sure how to check the resolution. Can you see it in this capture?: https://i.imgsafe.org/1462769b2b.png

Comment: I was using this monitor in a MBP 2009 with no problem. Now the quality is horrible (not just bad).

Comment: And here the Display Preferences capture: https://i.imgsafe.org/148ba35483.png

Comment: I'm convinced your external display is using its native resolution and refresh rate, and the consistency across multiple cables seems to rule out a cable issue. I'm out of ideas for now.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the LG monitor.  It worked fine HDMI to HDMI, UNTIL I did the upgrade to OS Sierra.  OS Sierra apparently doesn't support that resolution.  Apple is supposedly fixing.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get the LG 34UM65 (ultrawide monitor at 2560x1080) working with a 2017 MBP running macOS sierra following these instructions http://terrislinenbach.blogspot.co.uk/2015/12/running-lg-29um57-p-on-old-macbook-pro.html